# Remove non alpha numeric characters from string in AS2 only

Tags: string, replace, actionscript, actionscript-2

I need to remove non alphanumeric characters and spaces from a string using AS2, I know how to do it in AS3 but my server supports as2 only, so any ideas? I have searched for this and can't find anything that works.

```
myString = " !@%^$Guest &$(@$%^&";
```

**Desired output:**

```
myString = "Guest";
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "your server only supports as2"?

Comment: @Brian Flash Media Server as1 server side scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will provide you with the required solution for ActionScript 2:

```
function alphaNumeric(s:String)
{
    for(var i:Number=s.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if(!((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')))
            s = s.substr(0, i)+s.substr(i+1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
var B4:String = "!Text 123 _+$/,";
var AF:String = alphaNumeric(B4);
trace(B4);
trace(AF);  // ="Text123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using RegExp. AS2 does natively not support RegExp but I've seen some custom RegExp classes for AS2 out there in the web. Simply google for them and create a regular expression for removing these chars.
Alternatively, you can also use split().join() operations to remove these characters, but this wouldn't be as comfotable.

**EDIT:**
Example of uncomfortable way (AS2 code, not sure if working for AS1 though):

```
myString = " !@%^$Guest &$(@$%^&";

arr = new Array("!", "@", "%"); // put all chars to be removed in this array

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    myString = myString.split(arr[i]).join("");
}

trace(myString);
```

Comment: Hi, so with split().join() can you provide an example on that? just allowing a-zA-Z0-9  characters ...  thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it would be better to just remove the characters that are non a-zA-Z0-9, because there are too many special characters to add to the Array. So how could it be to put the alowed characters in the array instead? and if not in the array, then remove it? is that possible?

Comment: If you want to go with the uncomfortable way you need to add all chars manually to the array [arr = new Array("!", "@", "^", "$", [AND SO ON]);]